# MVC маршруты и БД

Tags: mvc, теория

Только начал знакомится с MVС. В сети миллион примеров как реализовать MVC модель на примере простенького сайта где как правило весь маршрут - это `news/index` и `news/1234`, делают это на основе регулярных выражений. Возможно это правильно, хотя выглядит конечно не очень. Меня интересует, как продолжить, например на сайте есть раздел "Электроника"(`somesite.com/electronika/`), если я все правильно понимаю, для этого раздела должен существовать контроллер `ElectronikaConroller` в нем `ActionIndex` метод, в котором мы вызываем "представление" главной страницы раздела "Электроника", соответственно в файле с маршрутами должен быть маршрут с ключом "Electronika". Эти разделы могут иметь `N` дочерних страниц, эти разделы из админ панели сайта необходимо создавать новые, так что для каждого раздела нужен свой контроллер или один общий, например `CatalogController`? Если один общий, тогда при переходе `somesite.com/catalog/`, получаем список каталогов (`ActionIndex`), потом `somesite.com/catalog/electronika`(`ActionSection`), получили список товаров.
На этом этапе я начинаю закипать. Меня интересует 2 вопроса :

1. Правильно ли я себе в воображении нарисовал, что существующие маршруты необходимо хранить в БД? Например есть таблица `catalogs`, и в ней поля `id, name, route` и тд. В `route` хранить ключ, например `electronika` а при переходе по ссылке `somesite.com/catalog/electronika` в контроллере `CatalogController` в методе `ActionSection` обратится к модели `Catalogs`, в которой я подключусь к БД, найду соответствие и отдам в представление результат если он есть?
2. Второй вопрос, это более глубокая вложенность, если первый хоть и не полностью понятен, но более ли менее я его могу себе представить, то тут совсем тупик. Например ссылка следующая `somesite.com/catalog/elektronika/kompyutery-i-komplektuyuschie/komplektuyuschie-i-aksesuary/moduli-pamyati/`, `catalog` - `CatalogController`, `electronika` - `ActionSection` а дальше что, как формировать более вложенные?

Код я еще не писал, вставлять нечего, прошу теорию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Если вы хотите добавлять новые маршруты из админки, то они могут храниться в бд. Конечно лучше сделать универсальный роутер в таблице `routes` с полями `pattern` и `handler`. handler это метод-обработчик, который вызывается при совпадении соответствующего маршрута, это Controller::action (если вы непременно хотите использовать классы).
2. Обратите внимание, что `elektronika/kompyutery-i-komplektuyuschie/komplektuyuschie-i-aksesuary/moduli-pamyati/` это уникальный идентификатор категории вашего каталога, и значит вы можете использовать его как параметр. Обычно это называют словом slug. Вы создаёте категории через админку и указываете для них slug -- уникальный кусок url. Создайте по нему хэш-индекс и поиск `where slug = 'elektronika/kompyutery-i-komplektuyuschie/komplektuyuschie-i-aksesuary/moduli-pamyati/'` будет быстрым (в MySQL нет хэш-индексов для InnoDB и MyISAM, но вы можете применить трюк вычисляя хэши самостоятельно, если надо я опишу подробнее). Теперь вам нужен только один маршрут для всего каталога: `~^/catalog/(?<slug>.+)$~i`.

main.php

```
<?php

// php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 main.php

$routes = [
    '^/catalog/(?<slug>.+)$' => 'catalog/category.php',
];

$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?? '/';
$handler = null;
$params = [];
foreach ($routes as $pattern => $handlerName) {
    $matches = [];
    if (preg_match('~' . $pattern . '~i', $url, $matches) === 1) {
        foreach ($matches as $name => $value) {
            if (is_string($name)) {
                $params[$name] = $value;
            }
        }
        $handler = require __DIR__ . '/' . $handlerName;
    }
}

if ($handler) {
    $response = $handler($params);
    echo $response;
} else {
    echo 'Not found';
}
```

catalog/category.php

```
<?php

return function($params) {

    $slug = $params['slug']?? '';

    // ищем категорию в бд
    // передаём результат во вью и получаем HTML
    // отдаём результат

    return '<b>' . $slug . '</b>'; // просто для демонстрации

};
```

Comment: Егор, у вас есть скайп? Вы можете дать платный урок? В main.php это Router у вас получился, верно? category.php это модель? А где контроллер? electronika ведь не может быть именем контроллера, так как мне тогда их наплодить придется под каждый раздел. Как хранить в БД slug? Например id-4, name-Электроника,slug-electronika потом под категория  subcategory_id-2, categoty_id-4(foreign), name-Компьютеры и комплектующие, slug-kompyutery-i-komplektuyuschie. Типо такого должно быть, а потом собирать это в ссылку?

Comment: @Winteriscoming Я интроверт, лучше текстом. Можно в телеграм ebanin, напишите, всё расскажу. Контроллер-экшн это catalog/category.php В бд храните slug целиком, собирать его надо при создании/перемещении новой категории. Тогда ссылку собирать не придётся.